# Call controller from controller in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, controller

Can i call admin panel controller from account controller?
I mean in account controller i set acessible parts of admin panel and i want to transfer that variable with accessible place to admin panel controller.

and now can i do sth like:

```
<?php

// Code here

$this->panel = new Admin_Panel();
$this->panel->accessibleparts = $this->data['accessible'];

?>
```

Or is it disallowed in mvc rules?

Comment: If you use PDO you should disable for debugging reasons the `mysql` extension so that you just do not use functions of it like `mysql_real_escape_string` - you don't need to.

Comment: check second part i resolved it

Comment: Then please add your solution as an answer and accept the answer so it's clear your question has been answered. For a second question, please open a new question.

Comment: Also I think your second part has been answered already in a duplicate question. Please use the search first.

Comment: Please come to [**chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) so we may help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is read about how it works in the manual: http://php.net/oop5

> ***Answer to your previous question:***

You get the following errors:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'radiolev'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/radiolev/public_html/top/toplist.class.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/radiolev/public_html/top/toplist.class.php on line 10

You then ask:

> I don't understand why it appears cause the mysql passwords are good.

No worries. You just made a little mistake. The mistake is that you make use of the function `mysql_real_escape_string` while not using a connection of the `mysql_*` extensions (note: extension, not database server).

In case you're calling that function without establishing a `mysql_*` extension database connection, PHP will automatically create one based on the settings provided in php.ini. That is normally only the host set to *localhost* - but wihout username and password.

This is why you see the first error that the connection fails and the second error is the result of the failed connection - there is no link to the databse, so ?`mysql_real_escape_string` can not work.

To solve the problem, just do not use `mysql_real_escape_string` when you're using mysql via `PDO`. Prepared statements is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff like this:

```
public function connect(){
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=radiolev_db', 'radiolev_user', 'ceowwyso1');
```

is all fine and dandy, but you're not actually storing that database connection object anywhere in your object. It's just a local variable in that particular method, and will be destroyed when the function exits. e.g. you're connecting, then as soon as your connct() method returns, the local `$db` variable goes out of scope, and your brand new database connection is closed and destroyed.

You need to store that $db in your **OWN** object, so it'll be preserved for later use, e.g:

```
 $this->db = new PDO(...);
```

instead.

And as everyone else above has said, you cannot mix mysql_*(), mysqli_*(), and PDO connections with each other. Each is a completely distinct and separate library (even though they all use the same underlying mysql low-level library). A connection established in one of those is completely distinct/separate/unusuable by the other libraries. Since you're using PDO to connect, you cannot use mysql_ functions, because mysql_ has no knowledge of anything going on in PDO.

Comment: still dont understand how i should it, could u show me any example?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `mysql_real_escape_string()` expects a connection (which you have made, just not using the mysql_* subset of commands).

Use PDO, and actual prepared statements, not whatever it is you're doing now.

```
$pdo = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE theColumn = :myParam');
$pdo->bindParam(':myParam', $_GET['data']);
$pdo->execute();
```

By 'call' I assume you mean use it.

Just add a return value, `return $db;` -- This would be at the end of your connect(), after the error mode was set.

Now

```
$db = new mysql();
$conn = $db->connect();
$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = ?');
$conn->execute(array('test'));
```

Comment: guys read second part of post not only first ;s

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mysql_real_escape_string` with PDO's [quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

You are getting a bunch of errors because `mysql_real_escape_string` is trying to use the last open connection used by `mysql_connect` (as explained in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)).  Since you are using PDO instead of the mysql_* functions, there is no connection and `mysql_real_escape_string` is throwing an error.